# Installing QGIS to virtual environment?

Tags: qgis, python, installation, mac

I'd like to install QGIS. I'm on  a system that defaults to Python 2.5x and I downloaded python 3.7x with homebrew. I created a virtual environment with this code.

```
brew install pyenv
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
exec $SHELL
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
pyenv activate my-virtualenv
```

I install python 3.6 and the modules `plotly`, `numpy`, `pygments`, `psycopg2`, `owslib`, and `PyYaml`.

Each of them are confined to the virtual environment. How do I install the package so that it loads and uses the Python from only the partcular environment.

Answer (score 5):

### Go Docker!

I would suggest to use a containerized solution.

You can for example run a full-fledge, stand-alone QGIS in a Docker container; it is very simple!

Start here and customize the environment editing the file `Dockerfile`.

At the time of writing, `QGIS 3.4.x` (LTS) and `QGIS 3.8.x` (latest) are supported.

https://github.com/rafdouglas/qgis_desktop_docker

https://hub.docker.com/r/rafdouglas/qgis_desktop

[image: QGIS on Docker]

*Disclaimer: I maintain both the repositories above :D*

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Note to users: the data files all have to be under `~/qgis34-files`. Drag-drop from elsewhere won't work.

Comment: Please note that as of today, also version 3.8 (aka "latest") is available, both on GitHub and as an automated image on DockerHub ;)